# Можно ли сказать: "город активно расстраивается"? (о застройке)

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать: "город активно расстраивается"? (о застройке)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, в повседневной профессиональной риторике застройщиков это и нормально (видимо, в более широкое употребление это переносят журналисты), но я бы критически отнёсся к факту фиксации их в словаре.  Независимо от контекста, всегда просматривается ненужный каламбур: сильно расстроился - разразился слезами, активно расстроился - закатил истерику и т. п.

Comment: Мне не удалось найти в Нацкорпусе ни одного примера, в котором бы населенный пункт расстраивался. Есть только о расстроенных людях, расстроенном здоровье, расстроенных  планах.

Comment: Это в словаре Кузнецова - видимо, журналисты подхватили на задании в какой-то проф. среде. Город расстраивается! - заголовок сюжета Бийского телевидения.

Answer (score 2):

[**расстро́иться**](http://www.rus-gos.spbu.ru/index.php/words/show/13906)
расстро́ится, св.
*Разг.* Активно строясь, увеличиться, занять больше места.
*Коттеджный поселок сильно расстроился за последние годы.*

*Потом город расстроился, разросся. Застроилась и эта его прилегающая к Невскому проспекту часть.*
Д. Калинина. Готовь завещание летом

*За те годы, когда Анатолий был в детском доме и в армии, а затем работал на северных нефтепромыслах, город расстроился.*
Н. Сташков. Идентификация убийцы. Час расплаты

*Цирк уродцев приехал в среду, остановился на окраине города, расстроился, расцвел.*
В. Вавикин. Желание верить

Глагол вполне "употребительный", только необходимо избегать двусмысленностей и нелепых ситуаций, которые вполне возможны при использовании в речи многозначных слов.
[Он расстроился из-за того, что пригород расстроился.]

Расстраивается = активно строится, активно расширяется.
Получается, что слово "активно" в словосочетании *активно расстраивается* излишне (если только автор не преследует какую-то особую цель или хочет добиться исключительной реакции на свои слова).

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть в словарь, то там указано второе значение глагола *расстроиться* *(расстраиваться)*: 2. РАССТРОИТЬСЯ,  св. Усиленно строясь, увеличиться, занять больше места. Завод расстроился, появились новые корпуса. Город сильно расстроился за последние годы.

Но в речи преобладает первое (негативное) значение глагола: потерять строй, сломаться, испортиться, а также огорчиться. Это нужно учитывать и употреблять слово в правильном контексте. Например, не стоит говорить так: Город хорошеет на глазах, он сильно расстроился за последние годы.